# getClusters() always returning an empty array (Using MarkerClustererPlus for Google Maps V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have the following code that loads a map and clusters the markers:

```
$scope.getMapHistory = function(locations){

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-history'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
    });

    var markers = [];
    locations.forEach(function(deviceLocation){
      //var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
      var devLat = deviceLocation._source.data.location[1];
      var devLng = deviceLocation._source.data.location[0];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(devLat, devLng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng });
      markers.push(marker);
    });

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

    //Test to get the clusters
    console.log(markerCluster);
    console.log(markerCluster.getClusters());
    console.log(markerCluster.getTotalClusters());

    markerCluster.fitMapToMarkers();

    $scope.hideLoading('loadingMap'); //Hides the loading gif

}
```

Until there everything is ok. The problem is that I want to access the clusters array and when I try to log the return of `markerCluster.getClusters()`, it returns a empty array. Also, `.getTotalClusters()` is returning 0.

[image]

However when I log the whole `markerCluster` and open it on the console I can see the clusters_ array:

[image]

The markers clustering works fine, but I cannot access the array of cluster nor the number of clusters. Does someone know what might be happening?
(I can give more details if my explanation isn't enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0 clusters since `MarkerCluster` is not getting fully initialized until map is loaded. The following example shows how to determine the number of clusters once the map is loaded:

```
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function(){           
   $scope.numOfClusters = markerCluster.getTotalClusters();
});
```

Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('mapApp', [])

    .controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.locations = [
            { Id: 1, name: 'Oslo', lat: 59.923043, lng: 10.752839 },
            { Id: 2, name: 'Stockholm', lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 },
            { Id: 3, name: 'Copenhagen', lat: 55.675507, lng: 12.574227 },
            { Id: 4, name: 'Berlin', lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 },
            { Id: 5, name: 'Paris', lat: 48.856127, lng: 2.346525 }
        ];

        $scope.initMap = function () {
            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 },
                zoom: 3
            });

            //init marker cluster
            var markers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locations[i].lat, $scope.locations[i].lng),
                });
                markers.push(marker);
            }
            var mcOptions = { imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m' };
            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer($scope.map, markers, mcOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function(){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                  $scope.numOfClusters = markerCluster.getTotalClusters();
                });
            });

        };

        $scope.initMap();
    });
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <h2>The number of clusters:{{numOfClusters}}</h2>
        <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will put your answer as the solution since it has a better implementation with the use of listeners. As you can see in the comments in the other answer I did it in the same way you explained here. Thank you. (:

Answer (score 4):

It seems as if you're asking for the clusters and total cluster count before the instance of MarkerClusterer has finished partitioning the markers, which is pretty quick but not really instantaneous.

One simple test would be to leave a couple of seconds before querying the properties:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

window.SetTimeout(function() {
    //Test to get the clusters
    console.log(markerCluster);
    console.log(markerCluster.getClusters());
    console.log(markerCluster.getTotalClusters());
},2000);
```

BTW, you are seeing the instance as containing markers because objects in the console are a reference to the original, meaning it does hold markers when you inspect it, but not necessarily when you logged it.

Comment: Yeah, I tested here and I could get the array. It's working now!
Thanks @amenadiel

Comment: I remember Markerclusterer firing the `clusteringend` event when it has finished clustering. The elegant solution would be to instance an empty MarkerClusterer, declare a listener for `clusteringend`, then use method addMarkers. Inside the listener you could operate on the fully loaded instance.

Comment: Yeah, I did this using the Listener and it is even a bit faster. Thansk a lot. (: